# Asp.net MVC - Area Attribute Routing is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have code like below

```
[RouteArea("Client")] 
public Class LoginController : Controller {
    [Route("register")]
    public ActionResult SignUp() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Attribute routing unfortunately is not working in the areas :/, if I will remove "register" route for signup, it will work just for for client/signup, but with route "register" it is not working.

I have added `[RouteArea()]`, tried with `[RoutePrefix]` but nothing is working correctly "Route Area" just enabled to use it with views (before that Razor couldn't find the view).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION.

1 Remove Area registration class from your area

2 Use this convention :

```
[RouteArea("Client")]
[RoutePrefix("login")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class LoginController : Controller
{

    [Route("")]
    // GET: Client/Login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("register")]
    // GET: client/login/register
    public ActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now you can use any route you want, with any prefix :)